# Opposite of endearment terms - does it exist, and/or have a name?

Tags: hypocorisms

Does the English language have any way to apply the reverse of endearment or diminution to a word - that is, make it sound big, dangerous, ugly, intense? "Pig" turns into "piggy" or "piglet"; "dog" has "doggie" or (recently) "doggo"... Is there (or was there ever) a reverse mechanism?

Comment: I guess a [dysphemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism) isn't quite what you're looking for?

Comment: There's  "[four letter word of choice]load" or "[flwoc]tonne", but I'm struggling to think of any clean examples!

Comment: @StuartF: Nope, these are separate words, "name-calling", if you please. I'm looking for what **Chemomechanics** described above.

Fantasy themes have "direwolves"; Pokemon have "Something" turning into "Somethingro" into "Somethingore". I'm looking for both a name and/or a proper language mechanism governing those, if there is one.

Comment: There are plenty of written references to [***were-pig***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+were-pig%22) and [***were-dog***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+were-dog%22) in Google Books. They're the ***mean, dangerous*** alternatives to diminutive ***piggy, doggie***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Were-creatures are human-animal monsters, not strictly "meaner versions of animals".

Comment: @SinusMackowaty: I'm well aware of that. But in practice the primary relevance of the *specifically **human** chimera* implications of the usage is that humans are clever, and often have access to resources that the *bestial* component wouldn't be able to use on its own. Animals can be "bad", but to be ***really mean***, you need some humanity! :)

Comment: There are languages that have such a suffix.  Italian, for example, has a *pejorative suffix* [**-accio**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-accio), which attaches to a noun to make it bad.  For example, *cagna* (female dog) + *-accio* = **cagnaccio** (an ugly and/or fierce dog).  English doesn't have a straightforward equivalent to this.

Comment: [Dire wolves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dire_wolf) were real creatures, btw.

Comment: In casual speech, people will sometimes attach the word "hell" to the front of a noun to say that it's very bad (literally "from hell").  A "hell-child" would be a very badly-behaved child, and "hell week" is used in both American universities for the week before final exams and in the US armed forces for the final week of basic training.  "Helldog" does not sound idiomatic, but "hellhound" is regularly used for supernaturally evil dogs in folklore.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to **-y** or **-ie**, **-o** is arguably antagonistic or alienating when added as a suffix. [**Bucko**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bucko) is defined as "a person who is domineering and bullying." **Friendo** was [memorably used](https://scottdistillery.medium.com/great-scene-no-country-for-old-men-f23a360db174) by the fearsome hitman Anton Chigurh in the film *No Country for Old Men*. Hunter Thompson reportedly named the paradigm-breaking "[**gonzo** journalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonzo_journalism)" after "[some Boston word for weird, bizarre](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gonzo)." The [Wictionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-o#English) contains many negative examples ("**uggo**, **weirdo**, **wino**, **cheapo**, **wacko**, **psycho**, **sicko**"). When applied to a person, the connotation seems to usually be negative.

On a separate note, **-zilla** (from Godzilla, connoting aggression and ferocity), **-gernaut** (from Juggernaut, connoting invincibility and unopposability), **-gate** (from Watergate, connoting a distasteful scandal), are some more specific suffixes that come to mind (**-tacular**, etc.), but these are all from existing words, distinct from typical diminutive forms.

Comment: This is similar to the Spanish usage of  final _on_, which indicates a "big" whatever, such as _bocón_, _comelon_, etc.